# XMLEventReader from ZipInputStream closes stream

Tags: java, xml, stream, zip

I want to stream a ZIP file containing several very large (~1GByte) XML files. I could read the data from each zip file into a buffer and create a XMLStream from that - but to save on memory I would prefer to process the data on the fly.

```
@Test
public void zipStreamTest() throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("archive.zip");
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
    ZipEntry ei;

    while ((ei = zis.getNextEntry()) != null){      
        XMLEventReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(zis);
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent xe = xr.nextEvent();
            // do some xml event processing..
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
    }
    zis.close();
}
```

The problem: I'm getting a `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` when executing `zis.closeEntry();`. When I remove that line, the same error is thrown at `zis.getNextEntry()` which closes previous entries if they're still open automatically.

It seems that my XML stream reader is breaking the stream at the end of the XML file so that the rest of the zip can't be processed.

Do I have an implementation error or is my conception of how streams work incorrect?

Note: To make this a minimal reproduceable example all you need is a zip file "archive.zip" which contains any valid XML file (no subdirectories inside the zip!). You can then run the  snippet using JUnit.

Comment: [The implementation of XMLEventReader](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.xml/share/classes/com/sun/xml/internal/stream/XMLEventReaderImpl.java) doesn’t appear close the underlying source, unless you call its `close()` method explicitly, so I’m guessing you are calling close() somewhere.  Consider providing a [mre] in your question.

Comment: I would recommend using `ZipFile` instead of `ZipInputStream`, as suggested in [answer by Alexandra Dudkina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64956918/5221149), but if you're processing a data stream while e.g. downloading, and therefore want to keep using `ZipInputStream`, you should wrap it is a [`CloseShieldInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) *(or other similar helper class)* inside the `getNextEntry()` loop.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks so much! Your solution works great. Please formulate your solution as an answer so that I can accept it. Re:ZipFile: This is the obvious solution, but my zip source and destination are not files but network streams and/or database sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `ZipFile` instead of `ZipInputStream`, as suggested in [answer by Alexandra Dudkina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64956918/5221149).

However, if you're processing a data stream while e.g. downloading, and therefore want to keep using `ZipInputStream`, you should wrap it in a [`CloseShieldInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)<sup>1</sup> inside the `getNextEntry()` loop:

```java
while ((ei = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    XMLEventReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new CloseShieldInputStream(zis));
    // Process XML here
    zis.closeEntry();
}
```

<sup>*1) Or other similar helper class from third-party library of your choice.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could try to open separate InputStream for each entry using `java.util.zip.ZipFile`:

```
@Test
public void zipStreamTest() throws Exception {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("archive.zip");
        Iterator<? extends ZipEntry> iterator = zipFile.entries().asIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ZipEntry ze = iterator.next();
            try (InputStream zis = zipFile.getInputStream(ze)) {
                XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(zis);
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    XMLEvent xe = reader.nextEvent();
                    // do some xml event processing
                }
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting my zips from network streams, so ZipFile is not an adequate tool. Andreas found a solution using CloseShieldInputStream which solves the problem using the desired approach.